# weighted sum in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `column1` and `column_2` in `some_table`. `column_2` can take 3 values, and I want to do the sum of all `column1*(column2+1)` values, (say the scalar product of (`column1`)*{i} and (`column_2+1`)*{i} vectors, where `i` is the rank of the row).

Of course I can do

```
SELECT column1, column_2 AS c FROM some_table
```

extract rows and process to the weighted sum. But is there an SQL query to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put an expression in the `SUM()` function.

```
SELECT SUM(column1*(column2+1)) AS weighted_sum
FROM some_table
```

It can be more complex:

```
SELECT SUM(column1 * IF(column2 = '$', column3, column4+1)) AS weighted_sum
FROM some_table
```

Comment: thank you Barmar, suppose know I want some more complex function on column2 is that possible ?

Comment: You can put ANY expression in there.

Comment: to make it more precise, suppose it is not an `algebraic` function but something more conditional : say if `column2 == $` then the function returns value `$`

Comment: Since MySQL has an `IF()` function that you can use in expressions, you can do that. Standard SQL is more verbose, you have to use a `CASE` expression, but it's still possible. Maybe it's time for you to study up on the functions available in MySQL?